# Can multilevel dataframe be styled using styler - pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have this multi-level dataframe which I'm converting to html, but I want to apply styling to the first row of headers, second row of headers, and data for specific columns. How would I do that?  Here's the styling I have so far which would be applied to second level of dataframe:

```
df.style.set_table_styles({
                        'LW Units': [{
                            'selector': 'th',
                            'props': [('background', '#E2EFDA !important')]
                        }],
                        'LW $': [{
                            'selector': 'th',
                            'props': [('border-right', '2px solid black !important'), ('border-left', '1px solid black !important'),
                                      ('background', '#FFF2CC !important')]
                        }],
                    }, overwrite=False). \
                        format("{:.1f}", subset=[
                        'LW $',
                        'LW Units',
                    ], na_rep='', thousands=",").to_html(fileName)
```

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YjTN.png)

Comment: That's a _lot_ of styles and undefined variables. Can you reduce your example to a much smaller set of formats with a sample DataFrame. Preferably an example entirely contained within this question ([mre]) and a mock up of the HTML/CSS you want to be generated (expected output)?

Comment: So above is an example of the code I'm doing and an example of the table.  Since I'm applying all styling to the secondary level of the data frame, I'd like to know how  do I specify the secondary level columns to style?